# Printing linked-list in python

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

In my task first I need to make single linked-list from array.

My code:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self,data):
   self.data = data
   self.next = next

class Lista:
   def __init__(self, lista=None)
      self.head = None
   
   def ispis(self):
      printval = self.head
      while printval .next is not None:
         print(printval.next.data)
         printval = printval.next


if __name__ == '__main__'
   
   L = Lista ([2, "python", 3, "bill", 4, "java"])
   ispis(L)
```

With function ispis I need to print elements of linked-list. But it says name "ispis" is not defined. Cannot change ispis(L) !

EDIT: removed next from and ispis(self) is moved outside Lista class

while printvla.**next** is not None:

EDIT2:
It shows that L is empty so thats why it won't print anything. Should I add elements to class Node ?

Comment: `ispis` is a method of `Lista`. You need to call it on the instance: `L.ispis()`. If you wanted to call it as you have where you pass `L` explicitly, you'd use `Lista.ispis(L)` (although this syntax isn't recommended).

Comment: Please repeat your tutorial materials on using classes, methods, and instances.  The correct format is to invoke an instance function *from the instance*:  `L.ispis()`

Comment: I cannot change calling function.

Comment: `ispis(L)` is wrong and will not work. You must change it.

Comment: I know but task is to use it like that

Comment: that's dumb. But i'm not your teacher. Did your instructor tell you that you had to use classes?

Comment: Yes. We usually use L.ispis() but never had this example and I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: If you must use that, then you'd need to create an external function called `ispis` that accepts `L`, then have it call `Lista.ispis` on `L`'s behalf. I don't know of any way to make that code work using only the method.

Answer (score 0):

`ispis` is a method in a class. But you are calling the function as if it is a normal function outside the class.

Atleast you have created the object correctly. Below would be the correct way of calling the method inside the class.

```
L.ispis()
```

Comment: Thanks, changed that. But it doesn't print anything.

Comment: That's something wrong with your code. But this is the proper way to call a method in a class.

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment. If the instructor is trying to teach you how to create linked lists, you need to go back to what you need to do:

1. A node when set up for the first time only needs the data. Typically the next pointer/value would be set to `None` (meaning no next member).
2. Your `__init__` method for your `Lista` class needs to do something with its argument.
3. I believe if you need to use your `ispls` function to operate on a class, then the function probably isn't supposed to be a member of `Lista`.
4. I think your `ispls` loop shouldn't be testing its `.next` member. This would fail if you had a `None` to begin with. You should be testing the current instance rather than its `next`. That way, when you move on to the next node, if it's `None`, it gets out of the loop.
5. Be careful with the keyword `next`. I would avoid using it as a class attribute. Also the literal `next` would just give you the built-in command.

At the bare minimum, you would want to iterate over the `lista` argument in `__init__`, creating a `Node` for each one, saving the previous node for the next operation.

```
   if lista is None:
       self.head = None
       return
   prev = None
   for data in lista:
       node = Node(data)
       if prev is None:
           self.head = node
       else:
           prev.next = node
       prev = node
```

But again, I believe that is what the instructor wanted you to figure out. Hope this helped.

--B

Comment: Problem is I never saw anything complex like this and I don't even know how to start coding this properly

Comment: Well, start small, and good luck! What you need to note with a linked list is that it's a bunch of data with a pointer to the next piece. If you set up your pieces right, it will all fall into place. I hope my snippet helped somewhat.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to append linked-list and print it. Now I have another function but I'll spend some time playing with it.